# Docker login: cannot input value for username on windows + powershell

Tags: docker, boot2docker

The username would not show up when using the boot2docker or Power shell client to connect to docker hub.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -u/-p/-e flags of docker login. for username,password and email as a workaround.